# In spring mvc, how to link to another jsp using @RequestMapping?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Actually, I have a welcome page(**welcome.jsp**). There is a link called "Contact us" in welcome page. I also have the **contactinfo.jsp**. I want to connect the link(Contact us) to the **contactinfo.jsp**. How to make it works?

I've tried, but it doesn't work. The welcome page is working, but I click the link "Contact us", its not going to **contactinfo.jsp**. See below is welcome controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String welcome(Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("greeting", "Welcome to Luke's Book Store!");
    model.addAttribute("tagline", "The one and only amazing web store");

    return "welcome";
}

@RequestMapping("/contactinfo")
public String contactinfo() {

    return "contactinfo";
}
```

This is my dispatcherServlet:

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven enable-matrix-variables="true"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.jiachangyang.ebookstore" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id= "messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages"/> 
</bean>

<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/WEB-INF/css/" />
```

This is the link in "welcome.jsp":

```
<a href="contactinfo">Contact us</a>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I find out the answer is `<a href="contactinfo">Contact us</a>`

```
@RequestMapping("/contactinfo")
public String contactinfo() {

    return "contactinfo";
}
```

Comment: I can't see the difference between the code in your question and the code in your answer?

Comment: I cant see any difference too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="location='contactinfo'">Contact us</a>
```